# confusion between firebase and socket.io in android?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, socket.io

I have an app that works with socket.io to get data and updates in real-time, but in some cases I am using Firestore so when connecting to the socket, use Firebase, disconnect from the socket then try to reconnect to socket it shows me **xhr polling error**
this is the code of Firebase

```
    fun signInSnapshotListener(userItem: UserItem, mContext: Context) {
           var currentExtensionSignInItem: signInItem? = SignInItem()
            val app = FirebaseApp.getInstance("test")
    
            val fireStore: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(app)
    
            val emailOrUsername: String = if (userItem.email != null) {
                userItem.email.toString()
            } else {
                userItem.username.toString()
    
            }
    
            val docRef: DocumentReference =
                fireStore.collection("signIn")
                    .document(emailOrUsername.lowercase(Locale.getDefault()))
            docRef.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, e ->
                if (e != null) {
                    Log.e("extensionListener", e.toString())
                }
                if (snapshot != null) {
                    if (snapshot.data != null) {
                        if (snapshot.data!!.contains("uidExt")) {
                            val uidExt:ArrayList<String> = snapshot.data!!["uidExt"].safeCast()
    
    
                            if (currentExtensionSignInItem!!.uidExt.size == 0 || !uidExt.containsAll(
                                    currentExtensionSignInItem!!.uidExt
                                )
                            ) {
    
                                CustomToast.showInformationToast(
                                    mContext,
                                    mContext.getString(R.string.extConnected)
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        currentSignInItem!!.convertDocumentSnapshotObject(snapshot.data as HashMap<String, Any>)
                    }
                } else {
                    FirebaseRepository.instance().clearPersistence()
                    currentSignInItem = SignInItem()
                }
            }
        }
```

I am getting this error also when trying to reconnect

```
    E/AppUpdater: The server is down or there isn't an active Internet connection.
        java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to test.com/****:****:****::****:****:***
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:147)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:411)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:248)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
            at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1072)
            at com.github.javiersantos.appupdater.ParserJSON.readJsonFromUrl(ParserJSON.java:81)
            at com.github.javiersantos.appupdater.ParserJSON.parse(ParserJSON.java:41)
            at com.github.javiersantos.appupdater.UtilsLibrary.getLatestAppVersion(UtilsLibrary.java:282)
            at com.github.javiersantos.appupdater.UtilsAsync$LatestAppVersion.doInBackground(UtilsAsync.java:68)
            at com.github.javiersantos.appupdater.UtilsAsync$LatestAppVersion.doInBackground(UtilsAsync.java:15)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:394)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:305)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

> BTW: this is my api link not the socket link
> test.com/**----**:**----**:**----**::**----**:**----**:**---**